# Regular expression usage in command line - replace space with %20 inside href

Tags: html, regex, bash, perl, sed

Find/replace space with %20

I must replace all spaces in `*.html` files which are inside `href="something something .pdf"` with `%20`.
I found a regular expression for that task:

```
find    : href\s*=\s*['"][^'" ]*\K\h|(?!^)\G[^'" ]*\K\h
replace : %20
```

That regular expression works in text editors like Notepad++ or Geany.
I want use that regular expression from the Linux command line with sed or perl.
Solution (1):

```
    cat test002.html | perl -ne 's/href\s*=\s*['\''"][^'\''" ]*\K\h|(?!^)\G[^'\''" ]*\K\h/%20/g; print;' > Work_OK01.html
```

Solution (2):

```
    cat test002.html | perl -ne 's/href\s*=\s*[\x27"][^\x27" ]*\K\h|(?!^)\G[^\x27" ]*\K\h/%20/g; print;' > Work_OK02.html
```

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser for this job, e.g.: xmlstarlet.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you don't properly escape the single quotes in your program.

If your program is

```
...[^'"]...
```

The shell literal might be

```
'...[^'\''"]...'

'...[^'"'"'"]...'

'...[^\x27"]...'    # Avoids using a single quote to avoid escaping it.
```

So, you were going for

```
perl -ne 's/href\s*=\s*['\''"][^'\''" ]*\K\h|(?!^)\G[^'\''" ]*\K\h/%20/g; print;'
```

---

Don't try do everything at once. Here are some far cleaner (i.e. far more readable) solutions:

```
perl -pe's{href\s*=\s*['\''"]\K([^'\''"]*)}{ $1 =~ s/ /%20/rg }eg'                # 5.14+

perl -pe's{href\s*=\s*['\''"]\K([^'\''"]*)}{ (my $s = $1) =~ s/ /%20/g; $s }eg'
```

Note that `-p` is the same as `-n`, except that it cause a `print` to be performed for each line.

---

The above solutions make a large number of assumptions about the files that might be encountered<sup>[1]</sup>. All of these assumptions would go away if you use a proper parser.

If you have HTML files:

```
perl -MXML::LibXML -e'
   my $doc = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file($ARGV[0]);
   $_->setValue( $_->getValue() =~ s/ /%20/gr )
      for $doc->findnodes(q{//@href});
   binmode(STDOUT);
   print($doc->toStringHTML());
' in_file.html >out_file.html
```

If you have XML (incl XHTML) files:

```
perl -MXML::LibXML -e'
   my $doc = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file($ARGV[0]);
   $_->setValue( $_->getValue() =~ s/ /%20/gr )
      for $doc->findnodes(q{//@href});
   binmode(STDOUT);
   $doc->toFH(\*STDOUT);
' in_file.html >out_file.html
```

---

1. Assumptions made by the substitution-based solutions:

   - File uses an ASCII-based encoding (e.g. UTF-8, iso-latin-1, but not UTF-16le).
   - No newline between `href` and `=`.
   - No newline between `=` and the value.
   - No newline in the value of `href` attributes.
   - Nothing matching `/href\s*=/` in text (incl CDATA sections).
   - Nothing matching `/href\s*=/` in comments.
   - No other attributes have a name ending in `href`.
   - No single quote (`'`) in `href="..."`.
   - No double quote (`"`) in `href='...'`.
   - No `href=` with an unquoted value.
   - Space in `href` attributes aren't encoded using a character entity (e.g `&#x20;`).
   - Maybe more?

   (SLePort makes similar assumptions even though they didn't document them. They also assume `href` attributes don't contain `>`.)

Comment: Props for providing the proper parsing code that I couldn't figure out myself :-)

Answer (score 1):

An xml parser would be more suited for that job(eg. [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/), [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html),...), but if you don't have newlines in your `a` tags, the below sed should work.

Using the `t` command and backreferences, it loops over and replace all spaces up to last `"` inside the `a` tags:

```
$ sed ':a;s/\(<a [^>]*href=[^"]*"[^ ]*\) \([^"]*">\)/\1%20\2/;ta' <<< '<a href="http://url with spaces">'
<a href="http://url%20with%20spaces">
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have neglected to escape the quotes inside the string you pass to Perl. So Bash sees you giving `perl` the following arguments:

1. `s/href\s*=\s*[][^'`, which results from the concatenation of the single-quoted string `'s/href\s*=\s*['` and the double-quoted string `"][^'"`
2. `]*Kh`, unquoted, because `\K` and `\h` are not special characters in the shell so it just treats them as `K` and `h` respectively

Then Bash sees a pipe character `|`, followed by a subshell invocation `(?!^)`, in which `!^` gets substituted with the first argument of the last command invoked. (See "History Expansion > Word Designators" in the [Bash man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).) For example, if your last command was `echo myface` then `(?!^)` would look for the command named `?myface` and runs it in a subshell.

And finally, Bash gets to the sequence `\G[^'" ]*\K\h/%20/g; print;'`, which is interpreted as the concatenation of `G` (from `\G`), `[^`, and the single-quoted string `" ]*\K\h/%20/g; print;`. Bash has no idea what to do with `G[^" ]*\K\h/%20/g; print;`, since it just finished parsing a subshell invocation and expects to see a semicolon, line break, or logical operator (or so on) before getting another arbitrary string.

Solution: properly quote the expression you give to `perl`. You'll need to use a combination of single and double quotes to pull it off, e.g.

```
perl -ne 's/href\s*=\s*['"'\"][^'\" ]*"'\K\h|(?!^)\G[^'"'\" ]*"'\K\h/%20/g; print;'
```

Comment: @ikegami Huh, I wasn't familiar with `\K`. Anyway, the expression I had in my answer was not intended to support spaces. It would be easy to add that capability - in fact I see you used this in your own answer. So I think it's a little unfair to say the OP's regex is far better than the double substitution technique on that basis.